# Using Slider Ui to control a carousel (to go to a certain slide on a certain value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Good morning all, I have been trying to create this "thing" for a while, but my brain isnt playing along!
I am trying to create a slider feature (using http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps) where the user selects amount they spend on *item*, then they click "calculate" which then takes them to a carousel slide which has a info on relevant to *item* value (its all built with carousel cycle2).

Hope I've explained this ok - I banged up a super quick fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/P4FrJ/

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" id="s1"
data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
data-cycle-timeout="0"
data-cycle-prev="#prev"
data-cycle-next="#next"
data-cycle-slides="> div"
>
<div class="binbarberbg white"> 
<div class="container pagewidth">   
    <div class="col-md-6" id="1" >
      <p> <label for="amount">select amount you spend on *item*:</label> <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"></p>

      <div id="slider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="calculate button" id="calculate">Calculate</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="slide2">£10</div>
<div id="3" class="slide3">£20</div>   
<div id="4" class="slide2">£30</div>
<div id="5" class="slide3">£40</div>     
<div id="5" class="slide3">£50</div>     
</div>
    <div style="height: 200px; clear: both;"></div>
<div class="center">
<a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a> 
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>



   $(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  value:10,
  min: 10,
  max: 50,
  step: 10,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + ui.value );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "£" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});

$( ".selector" ).slider({
change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to bind a click event handler function on your `#calculate` link.
This function will retrieve the slider value and make a call to the `goto` function of the carousel as described in the [carousel API](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/):

```
$('#calculate').click(function(e) {
    // Retrieve the slider value (10, 20, 30, etc.), divide by 10
    // to get the corresponding carousel slide index (0 based)
    // and use the 'goto' function (cf. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/)
    $('#s1').cycle('goto', $('#slider').slider('value')/10);
});
```

I updated your <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4FrJ/3/)</kbd> to show it in action.

Comment: Thank you so much - you have just saved me hours of headache for something so simple!